# SharePoint Search Queries

Tags: 2013, search, ssom

I am running a search for a particular query that I want to export the documents from.

When I run the query I base the total count on the [TotalRowsIncludingDuplicates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.office.server.search.query.resulttable.totalrowsincludingduplicates.aspx) property as I want all items including any duplicates (this is the number actually displayed in the search centre when you run a search). When I look at the [TotalRows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.office.server.search.query.resulttable.totalrows.asp) property it tends to be quite a bit smaller.

I page the query using [RowLimit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.office.server.search.query.query.rowlimit.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [StartRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.office.server.search.query.query.startrow.aspx) while TotalResults <= TotalRowsIncludingDuplicates. When I get to the TotalRows value the remaining queries up to TotalRowsIncludingDuplicates return 0 results.

I can't explain this discrepancy as I would expect to see the full duplicate result number. In some cases there is a delta of over 1k items.

Can anybody explain this please?

Comment: If you are in control of the query, the [`TrimDuplicates`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.search.query.query.trimduplicates.aspx) 
property should solve your problem

Comment: Yeah, thanks I'm an idiot. It seems that it is true by default.